# Does Azure Functions throw 503 errors while app settings are being updated?

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-functions, signalr-hub

Whenever I update my application settings for a Function app and hit the Save button on Azure Portal, I observe that this action temporarily stops my function app while the changes are being persisted to the active worker(s). I need to understand if this is indeed the case or if I'm making a false assumption.

What happens exactly when app settings are updated in the portal?

- 503 is thrown while active worker(s) are being updated

OR

- Another worker is specialized with the new host file. The old worker(s) stop once this one becomes active.

I keep getting 503 Service Unavailable errors. Is there any way to avoid this in production? I need to periodically rotate connection strings/keys, but I can't afford to disrupt the service constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update the app settings, the app will be restarted. That's why you got 503 error.

Usually in the production environment, we will not change the app settings frequently.

Anyway, to avoid such situation, you can use the [slot feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots)

Comment: Thanks. I used deployment slots with auto swap turned on, but the issue was still there. If I'm running 10 workers in production, does the deployment slot also create 10 workers? If it creates only 1 worker, will auto swap cause downtime issues?

Comment: @user246392 Yes, deployment slot will also create 10 workers. If you need to periodically rotate connection strings/keys, you can create two slots for your application. After updating the settings on slot2, then swap your current slot to slot2. It will not cause downtime issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have a Timer trigger that kicks in every minute. Will this run in the deployment slot as well? I'd like it to run only once, not twice.

Comment: @user246392 Timer trigger is different from the other triggers, if a function app scales out to multiple instances, only a single instance of a timer-triggered function is run across all instances. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#scale-out

Comment: Thanks. How do I decide whether the production slot or deployment slot gets the timer trigger?