# Azure Functions: How to load balance between multiple Function apps in the same region

Tags: azure, azure-functions, load-balancing, serverless, azure-traffic-manager

Is it possible to load balance between multiple `Function` apps (say 10 of them) on consumption plan in the same region? Each app would have the same source code and can individually be upgraded to prevent downtime. Unfortunately, sometimes I get 503 errors when I deploy changes to a `Function` app, in which case I have to manually restart the app in the portal. Auto-swap has the same issues. This is not acceptable in a production environment, so I'm thinking of using multiple apps. I looked into using `Traffic Manager`, but that seems to be suited for a multi-region deployment.

Comment: I agree. MS is famous for overpromising and underdelivering. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767337/azure-function-deployments-cause-brief-503-errors-even-when-auto-swap-is-turned. Working with `Functions` hasn't been the most pleasant experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Traffic Manager also for backends that are all in the same region. However, I would rather recommend to use Azure Front Door as it provides more capabilities and faster failover times.

Comment: If I had a Function app deployed in US West, Central, and East and a Cosmos DB in Central, and Front Door in Zone 1, can you help me understand how outbound data transfers are charged? Will I pay for outbound bandwidth 3 times if, say, the data is routed from Central (Cosmos DB) to West (Function) to wherever Zone 1 is located?

Comment: Front Door is a global service and pricing depends on where the client is connecting from  (those are the Zones 1,2,3) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/frontdoor/ Regarding cosmos db: if your Function is deployed in multiple regions, I would recommend to also enable geo replication on cosmos

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same solution, as Microsoft recommended for HA (totally agree with previous commentator):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-geo-disaster-recovery